# Will any starter relay / solenoid do? For my motorcycle

Tags: motorcycle, starter, yamaha, tt600

I'm looking for a starter relay / solenoid for my 2004 Yamaha TT600RE. That part seems to be scarce for this bike.

How interchangeable are solenoids for motorcycles? Will any Yamaha 600cc solenoid fit this bike?

If I find just any ol' solenoid with 180 A amperage and 4,4 Ω ± 5% resistance and pop it in there, is it likely to get the job done? How about any motorcycle solenoid, period (in a pinch)? I've seen some cheap "universal" solenoids, are these to be avoided?

Edit: [this is what the starter relay for my bike looks like](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Yamaha-TT-600-E-New-Starter-Solenoid-Relay-12v-/221077164009?)

[here is a cheap universal one that looks like it would work](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Universal-12V-Starter-Relay-Solenoid-Pit-Monkey-Quad-Bike-Scooter-Motorcycle/111625692885?_trksid=p2047675.c100009.m1982&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D32956%26meid%3D340afee32316492c95df2b427d7c7419%26pid%3D100009%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D10%26mehot%3Dlo%26sd%3D221077164009)

Comment: Almost any 12v solenoid will fulfill your requirement.   Get a used one, they are typically very robust.  I prefer Honda but that is simply my opinion.  Good luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: Maybe?

As long as it is a 12v motorcycle starter relay you should be fine. The problem is whether or not it will fit your bike physically (that is whether the size of the solenoid will fit into the compartment designated in your motorcycle, and whether you have bullet, spade etc etc).

I have used a few of the cheap Chinese ones off eBay and they are hit and miss. One has stayed in an old CB400 for years with no problem. I put one in a CB360 and it blew in less than 3 months.

I've also taken solenoids from one model of bike and crimped new connectors to make it fit a different model bike with no problems.

Bottom line is a starter solenoid is a simple electro-mechanical switch: provided it is 12volt you can theoretically make any relay fit any bike.

Comment: Your answer is spot on. Basically, as long as the solenoid can handle the amperage, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful answer :) good to know I don't have to spend an arm and a leg for the OEM one.